# I'm looking for a particular insertion algorithm but I can't think of the name

Tags: c#-4.0, sorting

Basically I have a method that will take any set of numbers with a selected value and reorder them ascending keeping track of the new selected value.

So {21, 2, 9, 13} selectedVal = 9   becomes  { 1, 2, 3, 4 } selectedVal = 2

What I need to do now is be able to swap 2 numbers and keep the order intact. If I want to swap 2 with 4 I need 3->2 and 4->3 but also the other way around like swapping 3 with 1 so 1->2 and 2->3.

I'm sure there is a proven algorithm for this and I will probably create my own for fun tomorrow but I'd like the fastest solution to use in my actual application.

The name of the algorithm or any useful links would be appreciated. I am using C# 4.0 if that matters at all.

EDIT - I came up with my own solution that I believe works on paper but I'd still like a reply if someone knows a better solution.

Assuming ordered list always starts at 1 which it does in my case...

```
if (newpos < currpos)
   for (int i = newpos-1; i < currpos-1; i++)
   {
       array[i] += 1;
       array[currpos-1] = newpos;
   }     
else if (newpos > currpos)
   for (int i = newpos-1; i >= currpos-1; i--)
   {
       array[i] -= 1;
       array[currpos-1] = newpos;
   }  
else // do nothing since they are trying to swap to the same place
```

Comment: Is this some kind of tag array? Where one array contains indexes into another? I'm totally lost on how `{21, 2, 9, 13}` becomes `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

Comment: 2->1,  9->2,  13->3,  21->4.

Comment: So you have an array of values, and an array of indexes that maintains the order? So when you swap 9 and 13 in the values array, you want to reflect those changes in the index array? If that's what you're attempting, it's sometimes referred to as a "tag sort", when sorting. The index array is often called a "tag array." As written, your question is very confusing and impossible to answer.

Comment: Tag sort, eh? Thanks, my algortithm does indeed work for my needs but I will check out the tag sort as well.